# How to run long loop needs than allowed maximum execution time

Tags: php

I have a `foreach` loop but it takes long time to reach to its end, and that time is more than allowed maximum execution `max_execution_time` that allowed by my shared hosting server.

Also i can not alter `max_execution_time` value cause i know such solutions

```
set_time_limit(0); // if `safe_mode` is off
// or
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds
```

All are not working and I'm not allowed to do so.

So I wonder if there any way like `sleep` or stop the loop after time to `sleep` for while then continue ! any idea to do so.

```
$arr = range(0, 50000000);

foreach ($arr as $number){

// do something using $number

}
```

Comment: Sleeping will just make your execution time longer. You'll have to split the job into smaller parts or make the code run faster.

Comment: Can you break your loop into smaller parts?

Comment: @AlexHowansky if i split the loop into small loops and by the end of each loop it redirect `header("Location: ./second_loop.php?stop=9999 "); ` to another file with the stopped position in the loop and so on .. does it looks good and each redirect as if i get the `max_execution_time` starts from the beginning or what do you think!

Comment: @symlink thank you, and i start thinking about splitting the loop into loops each loop in different file .. please check my previous comment and tell me your opinion.

Comment: since I cant tell what this project is for, using javascript could also be a solution.

Comment: @RehamFahmy, you shouldn't be doing so much in a single HTTP request. Consider offloading heavy jobs to the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are not allowed to do a change in `ini_set`, however, you have a pnp.ini for web requests and another for command-line stuff. So, if you change the settings for command-line, it will not affect the maximum execution time of the web requests.

When you say that `ini_set` was not working, I think you did not realize that this is unspecific of the exact problem, so I have to do an assumption about what not working means in your case. I think it means that even if you set a larger limit, the cycle still times out. However, if you run

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

then the script will run until the end. If it's issued by the operating system, as a cron job, for instance and not from a web request, then the upper execution time for web requests will remain unchanged even if you run `ini_set`.

Even though this should be enough for a solution, it is worth mentioning that if for some strange reasons you are not allowed to call `ini_set` even for cli php.ini, then you will have to send a request just before the timeout to the same page, passing your index, so the next request will know where to continue from. Do not cut this into several files, it's an antipattern.

And regardless of the solution you choose, please try to optimize your code. It is possible that you will not have any problems with the execution time if time is not wasted by the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use cookies for storing counter for each chunk of loop and then redirect to the same page

Splitting of the loop using of cookies

```
<?php

    $start = microtime(true);
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['count']) && !is_integer($_COOKIE['count'])){
    setcookie('count', 0);
    header("Location: http://my.loc/Myclass.php");
    exit;
}
    $count = $_COOKIE['count'];
    $arr = range($count, 5000000);
    $handle = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
    foreach ($arr as $item){
        fwrite($handle, $item . ',');

       if ($item%1000000 == 999999 ){
           setcookie('count', ++$item);
           header("Location: http://my.loc/Myclass.php");
           exit;
       }elseif($item == 5000000){
           setcookie('count', 0);
           $end = microtime(true);
           setcookie('time1', $end - $start);
           exit;
       }
    }
```

Another solution without cookies for splitting of loop

```
<?php
    $start = microtime(true);
    if (!isset($_GET['count'])){
        $count = 1;
        header("Location: http://my.loc/Myclass1.php?count=$count");
        exit;
    }
    $count = $_GET['count'];
    $arr = range($count, 500000);
    $handle = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
    foreach ($arr as $item){
        fwrite($handle, $item . ',');

       if ($item%100000 == 99999){
           ++$item;
           header("Location: http://my.loc/Myclass1.php?count=$item");
           exit;
       }elseif($item == 500000){
           $end = microtime(true);
           setcookie('time1', $end - $start);
           exit;
       }
    }
```

Comment: But I don't think it's a good solution because browsers don't allow many redirections and in the end you will see an error